# How to not show "unspecified error" when throwing exception

Tags: c#, exception, silent, unspecified

Somewhere in my code I want to throw an exception to stop its execution( as the possible error in question is deep in the stack). However, when I write`

```
throw new ArgumentException(
                    String.Format("There is a input error at X position. Execution will stop.");
```

I get a messageBox saying "unspecified error", and then the message. How can I make it so that "unspecified error" doesn't show? Making this messagebox not appear would also work, as I could replace it with a custom one...
`

Comment: You can add a high level exception handler on the app domain and show your custom error box there, then end the process (`Environment.Exit`). See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use Debug class, you can show errors in output line

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx